# How would I extract names separated by dots (.) and hyphens (-) in Python and just list them in a text file?

Tags: python, regex

I have CSV containing multiple emails in multiple columns extracted from my email inbox.
emails are held within pointy brackets such as this:

`<name-name.name@domain.com>, name.name@domain.com`
emails are also listed inside text of emails I would like to pull out

I would like to extract each name fragment and just list them in a text file.

I know I need to use regex - could someone help me, please? Thanks!

```py
import re

s = """
<name-name.name@domain.com>, name.name@domain.com
"""

emails = re.findall(r'[:,]\s*=?\s*(?:([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)?))?\s*=?\s*.*?([\w.]+@[\w.-]+)', s)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code -- I have a list of emails in object names emails

Comment: So what do you need to get in the end? What is the expected result? Why is the current code bad?

Comment: I have the emails saved in the object s but what I want is to search and find all names and list them in a text file such as the following:
`name, name, name` a name per line.... the names are in between hyphens and dots - I would then like to use this list to find all matching strings and remove them from an entire CSV file containing plain text from bodies of emails in order to anonymize them.

Comment: Unfortunately - your example above is not as useful as you think. `name-name.name@domain.com` implies an email like `john-john.john@domain.com`. Can you provide some made up examples that help to explain better how the emails are stored. eg. `john-smith.johnsmith@domain.com` or `firstname-middlename.lastname@domain.com`  or maybe the hyphen is optional, eg. `firstname.lastname@domain.com where firstname could have a hyphen` Be a bit more specific and you are more likely to get a response.

Comment: @ScottC Thanks for the reply -- The email addresses I am processing always have a separate -- as I said, there are hyphens and dots. I don't think it matters with the logic as I am trying to remove matching strings from plain text ( that is to remove names for anonymity) ex: name-name.name-name@company.com I will make a text DB with these names to loop through and do a simple find/match /remove from the plain text which is held in the 4th column of a CSV -- The email addresses are in first (to), second(from) and third (cc) columns of the CSV. The goal is to make a list from the first 3 columns

Comment: Do the names have numbers in them ?  `eg. john.smith05@domain.com`

Comment: Also - the way the names are formatted, (ie. spaces, hyphens, numbers, dots), can have an impact on how you write the regex. Without some clear examples, it is very difficult to answer this question.

Comment: I provided the most complicated examples! It drives me crazy that everyone on these sites are supposed to be here for help but can’t just answer the question. It’s question after question.. I appreciate how @fares-hassen just answered. There’s more value in giving an answer than answering a question with a question over and over. Then everyone gives it a down vote - hey, I’m asking a valid question for help - this, should get an upvote!

Comment: I don’t need the names to be compete - I am just taking account of the string itself so I can find / match and remove the string from the emails. Latinos offers have 4 or even more names. Jose-Rosa.Rodriguez-Alejandro-manero@business.com - no numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example provided, here is a possible solution:

```py
import re

#String containing names
s = """
<name-name.name@domain.com>, name.name@domain.com
"""

#Search for names in emails
pattern = re.compile(r'<(\w+)-(\w+).(\w+)@(?:.*)>|(\w+).(\w+)@(?:.*)')
emails = pattern.findall(s)

# Extract names from the email matches
names=[]
for e in emails:
    for name in e:
        #ignore blank names
        if name != '':
            names.append(name)

# Print the names
print(names)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['name', 'name', 'name', 'name', 'name']
```

---

However, if you change your example to the one provided in the comments:

```
#String containing names
s = """
<name-name.name@domain.com>, name.name@domain.com
Jose-Rosa.Rodriguez-Alejandro-manero@business.com
"""
```

Then I would change the search pattern to:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'<([\w-]+).([\w-]+)@(?:.*)>|([\w-]+).([\w-]+)@(?:.*)')
```

Which would give an output of:

```
['name-name', 'name', 'name', 'name', 'Jose-Rosa', 'Rodriguez-Alejandro-manero']
```

Comment: Thanks so much @ScottC - I will try it out. But actually the example as in Jose-Rosa, I would want the output as  [jose, rosa] each should be treated as it’s own name - not name-name, this is helpful though - thanks!

Comment: It would be easy enough to go through retrospectively and split the names by hyphen (if they exist). or even split them within the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a few lines in your file:

```
import re
file = ['<name-name.name@domain.com>, name.name@domain.com']
res=[re.findall(r'([-\w.]+)@',line) for line in file ]
t = []
for ele in res:
        for match in ele:
                t.extend(re.split(r'[-.]',match))
```

Comment: Thanks @Fares_Hassen -- Could you please make some comments so I know what this code snippet means? Please take a look at the changes I made above as I have all emails stored in an object names emails.